# dereference DateTime? to class.DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

Some how I'm getting a null reference exception on this, and I'm not sure why.

```
if (units.Min(sd => sd.MONTH_UNIT_APPLIES_TO) != null)
{
    DateTime? dt = (DateTime)units.Min(sd => sd.MONTH_UNIT_APPLIES_TO);
    // dt = {8/1/2012 12:00:00 AM}
    crctw.unitChecks.startDate = (DateTime)dt;  // // NullReferenceException here
}
```

The start date field is in this wrapper class:

```
public class checksWrapper
{
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Since it's a value type, I don't think I should have to use the new operator.

If the debugger says it has a date {8/1/2012 12:00:00 AM} then why am I getting a null reference?

Comment: Try `crctw.unitChecks.startDate = dt.Value;`

Comment: Either `crctw` or `crctw.unitChecks` evaluate to null. The casts are redundant (DateTime? -> DateTime -> DateTime? -> DateTime) and confusing.

Comment: @pst OP is debugging and it's not null, the problem must be the cast from nullable to default datetime.

Comment: @pst Indeed, that's possible too

Comment: @AndreCalil I believe it's a red-herring. The dt *must* be a `DateTime` (not `Nullable<DateTime>`) from above cast and null-check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either `crctw` or `unitChecks` is null. The variable `dt`is fine. You're just looking at the wrong side of the `=`...